# Local Notification is cleared from notification center after clicking the notification in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, localnotification

UILocalNotification is cleared from the notification center after clicking in iOS 8. But it is not cleared from notification center in iOS 7. Can I know what makes the notification clear from center?

Answer (score 0):

i dont have this behavior but i did have it with location services as you said...in that case it seems that the plugin was not working properly so i had to create the project from scratch (after updating cordova to latest) then added each plugin, that fixed my problem with location services BUT now i have a problem with local notification, again i dont see the option at all in my settings, but since you are seeing it this might be related with your app being installed just where prior (iOS7 installation) was in that case it make sense that if you delete you app you will NO see your app in local notification settings at all... this is definitively related with local-notification-cordova-plugin being a pain in the neck to work properly now im really sad to see that iOS8 is conflictive with the plugin i barely found...now i'm not sure what to do, if you find a local-notification-plugin that works with iOS8 PLEASE let me know!